# HttpClient send Auth header

Tags: c#, httpclient, digest-authentication

I'm using `HttpClient` to call some REST API with authentication like this:

```
_networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, apiKey);
_httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = _networkCredential };
_httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler);
```

This works nicely, but as defined in RFC2617 this will send every request without AUTH header, gets back a 401 and then sends the request a second time with AUTH header.

I'd like to get rid of the extra call without AUTH header to achieve better throughput. For BASIC AUTH I found the following example to manually add the BASIC AUTH header to every call:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{apiKey}")));
```

But my service insists on DIGEST AUTH. How can I achieve this in DIGEST AUTH?

I'd guess I'd have to call the service once and cache the AUTH HEADER for subsequent calls. But if the nonce changes I'd need to refresh the AUTH HEADER? How could this be solved?